# JQuery: trigger('change') vs trigger('change.select2')

Tags: jquery, html, triggers, jquery-select2

I have a select2 element (#project_id). I have a change event of this element as well.

```
$(document).on('change', '#project_id', function () {
     //my code...
}
```

The change event only triggers when I use the following:

```
$("#project_id").html('<option value="' + res.project_id + '">' + res.project_name + ' [ ' + res.project_id + ' ]</option>');
$("#project_id").val(res.project_id).trigger('change');
```

I want to understand why the change event does not trigger while using:

```
$("#project_id").html('<option value="' + res.project_id + '">' + res.project_name + ' [ ' + res.project_id + ' ]</option>');
$("#project_id").val(res.project_id).trigger('change.select2');
```

In both the cases, the select2 option is changed, but the event is triggered only in the first case.

Answer (score 0):

The [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) event fires when certain `form` elements change value. You bound a listener to that event and triggering it explicitly.

The `change.select2`event is a separate event and not associated with the dom elements. According to the [documentation](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events#limiting-the-scope-of-the-change-event):

> It's common for other components to be listening to the change event,
>   or for custom event handlers to be attached that may have side
>   effects. To limit the scope to **only** notify Select2 of the change,
>   use the .select2 event namespace

So it never reaches the "real" `select` element and hence, your handler isn't executed.

You can dig into [the source](https://github.com/select2/select2/blob/2ea17181e3e1ee3b1bea490f405c044385a11ae2/src/js/select2/core.js#L179) to see that's just using it to notify other `select2` components to update their display, etc.